# .text function in Python using selenium library

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
self.browser.get('https://www.mathblog.dk/tools/infix-postfix-converter/')

returnValue = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='post-4778']/div/form[1]/p/input[1]").text
```

### the infix box

`.text` function doesn't work it returns an empty string. Why is that happening?

Comment: please read [How to ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If your issue has solved, feel free to accept the answer with click on `√` icon.

Answer (score 0):

To extract text from `input` field use `.get_attribute('value')`.

Your have correct xpath, but css selector is better than xpath:

```
returnValue = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name=infix]").get_attribute('value')
print(returnValue)
```